# how to know that a successful upgrade has been completed via command

Tags: command-line

What message should be displayed on ubuntu command line to show that a successful upgrade has been completed (via command)?

Comment: Is no errors not enough?

Answer (score 1):

CLI programs normally use exit codes to specify if the command exited with success or something happened in the middle, `apt-get` is no exception.

That means that instead of

`sudo apt-get install foo`

(being foo some package that you want to upgrade manually of even install) you can use

`apt-get install foo && echo "Great success!" || echo "OMG do something! Dooooooooomed!"`

If the first command fails somewhere with an error, the first one will be executed, else the second one.

Of course you can replace the commands I used in the example with something more practical, such as, eg: mail someone or send a warning to everyone logged in to the computer. Get creative.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command to check whether the previous command succeeded or not,

```
echo $?
```

If the output of the above command displays `0`, means your previous command was succeeded.If it displays any number other than 0, your previous command was not succeeded.

```
[ $(echo $?) == 0 ] && echo "Your previous command was succeeded" || echo "Your previous command was not succeeded"
```

OR

```
((! $?)) && echo "Your previous command was succeeded" || echo "Your previous command was not succeeded"
```

Comment: `[ $(echo $?) == 0 ]` could be also written as `((! $?))`.

Comment: Moreover, you probably want either `=` or `bash` conditional command `[[` if you want to use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

After running

```
apt-get upgrade
```

run this:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

The exit status is stored in “$?” internal variable.

the exit status value varies from 0 to 255.

> 0 Successful execution of command
>
> 0 > command fails because of an error during expansion or redirection,
>   the exit status is greater than zero.
>
> 2 Incorrect command usage
>
> 126 Command found but not executable
>
> 127 Command not found

Comment: When i answer your answer was just `echo $?`.  I provide another syntax and some explanation. It's better to teach how to fish to just give a fish